# :first-letter on li elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to use a :first-letter pseudo element on a navigation menu.

HTML such as:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Navigation</li>
        <li>Navigation</li>
        <li>Navigation</li>
        <li>Navigation</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And CSS like:

```css
nav li:first-letter {font-size: 150%;}
```

I've also tried

```css
nav ul li:first-letter {font-size: 150%;}
```

to no help.

I can see it working for the first element on the `<ul>` tag if I adjust it to this:

```css
nav ul:first-letter {font-size: 150%;}
```

but still can't get exactly what I need; `<li>`'s inline whose first character is larger than the others.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock for the syntax hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `li` elements are all flowing inline (assuming you have a `display: inline` style that's not shown), the `:first-letter` pseudo-element will only pick up the very first letter out of that entire chunk of inline text. That is why `ul:first-letter` works, but `li:first-letter` does not.

Try making your list items inline blocks instead, so they continue to contain their text within their own boxes, while these boxes themselves flow inline. If necessary, zero out their margins and padding.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/jVBMp)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking at.  I neglected to realize that `display:inline-block;` would also work.

Comment: (edit) (snips) sorry, the comments I added seemed more like another new question than a continuance...

Answer (score 2):

Your first CSS snippet works fine, look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TRNrB/). You must have another css rule which override it.

Answer (score 1):

it seems as the created "Shadow" Markup from the Browser just inserts another element.

Something like:

```
<p><p:first-letter>H</p:first-letter>ello</p>
```

Did you try `:first-letter` selector with an inline-block and/or block element?

Try adding a `display:block`, that should work then.

Comment: I think he's just illustrating how pseudo-elements work. If that's the case, this answer misses the point completely.

Comment: Well, actually the illustration was there to show how the inlined element is created automatically if you use the pseudo selector :first-letter. Dunno why this misses the point completely, as it's the given problem by the questioner - because the font size is relative and not absolute to the parent elements and therefore would gain double the factor on size each inherited level.