# trying to get the first child and change its color

Tags: html, css, ejs

I have the following code in my ejs landing page:

```
<div class="content-wrap">
                <ul class="fly-in-text">
                    <% for(var i = 0; i < introText.length; i++){ %>
                    <li><%= introText[i] %></li>
                    <% } %>
                </ul>

                <a href="/home" class="enter-button">Enter</a>
            </div>
```

and in my css I have the following

```
li > :first-letter {
    color: var(--oc-green)
}
.welcome-section .content-wrap .fly-in-text li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 5em;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

I am trying to change the color of the first li element in this loop to a green color I have set. Is there another way I should point to the first li element?

Comment: `ul > li:first-child { color: var(--oc-green); }` ?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553539/first-letter-on-li-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:first-letter on li elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553539/first-letter-on-li-elements)

Comment: Do you mean first-child? If you want to “change the color of the first element in the loop”, you can’t use first-letter

Comment: when I use first letter the whole array of letters turns green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change color of `first-letter` of the first `li`, the code is below:

```
li:first-child:first-letter {
  color: var(--oc-green);   
}
```

If you need to change color of `first-letter` of every `li`, the code is below:

```
li:first-child {
  color: var(--oc-green);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `li > :first-letter` you need to change to `li:first-letter`:

```
li:first-letter {
    color: var(--oc-green);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.content-wrap ul li:first-child{
    color:green;
}
```